# How to connect to an IPSec VPN with a short (<20chars) PSK

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a work VPN which is using IPSec and a pre-shared key.  The recommended client is NCP Secure Entry (https://www.ncp-e.com/en/products/ipsec-vpn-client-suite/vpn-clients-for-windows-10-8-7-macos/) but there is no Linux version available.

I have an .ini file which looks like it has all the config I'd need to set up the connection.  I am using `strongswan` with the Gnome network manager plugin (`network-manager-strongswan`).

My problem is that strongswan (the UI plugin and the backend) enforce a minimum 20 character PSK, but my work VPN is using a 12-character PSK.  I have no way of getting that changed.  This is (rightly) an open bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan/+bug/1697536; the client is a stupid place to try and enforce server config.

**Is there any way of persuading strongswan to accept a short PSK?  If not, is there some other package I could use instead?**

I am so frustrated I am considering forking strongswan just to remove this limitation...

Comment: No, you can't get them to accept shorter PSKs. However, you could configure strongSwan via config files and initiate from the console (or automatically). Not sure if there is some other NM plugin that provides IKEv2 connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Shrew Soft VPN client (https://www.shrew.net/; can be installed with `apt install ike` and `apt install ike-qtgui`) allows a wide range of IPSec VPN connections including PSK/XAuth with short keys, and IKE v1 and v2.  In these respects it is more flexible than Strongswan.

I have managed to get it installed and connected to the VPN on Ubuntu 18.04, but only intermittently and it won't actually pass any network traffic.  YMMV.